# How to locate "Podfile" in iOS project? for add firebase to use facebook login

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I can't find this file and when I open new one it cannot install it.

I tried to open "pod init".

Are there other ways to do it?

In Mac

Comment: Have you read the "Install" and "Getting Started" instructions at https://cocoapods.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First navigate to the directory that you want pods to exist in.

Run:

$ sudo gem install cocoapods

$ pod init

then you should have a new Podfile.

To open it using vim Run:

$ vim Podfile

Once you've added your pods, Run:

$ pod install

to install them